# blade page is showing anything

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make an index page but for whatever reason its not showing anything.
This is my routes

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('student','StudentsController');
Route::resource('student/absense','AbsensesController');
```

as you can see im using resources so my routes are already generated.

This is my controller

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('student.absense.index');

            }

    /**
```

My view is something like:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<table class="table ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Prenome</th>
      <th scope="col">Nom</th>
      <th scope="col">Niveau</th>
      <th scope="col">group</th>
      <th scope="col">Payment date End</th>
      <th scope="col"> More options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>



    <tr>

      <th scope="row"></th>
    </tr>

</tbody>

</table>
@endsection
```

And this is the route im getting in cmd:

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | student/absense                | absense.index    | App\Http\Controllers\AbsensesController@index
```

the page im getting is empty without any error. any idea why ?

Btw index is inside absense folder and absense folder is inside student folder.

Comment: I assume you have those routes in the `web.php` file and not in the `api.php` or one of the others?

Comment: Seems like something went wrong in your routes. Try without the `::resource` and see if using `::get` fixes it. Do the other routes work?

Comment: im useing on web.php. and ye there is something wrong with route which i cant see.

Comment: its still not working even after i changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a conflict with the ordering of your routes:

Your are adding

```
Route::resource('student','StudentsController');
```

The resource adds the following show route:

```
student/{student}
```

Then you are adding

```
Route::resource('student/absense','AbsensesController');
```

The resource adds the following index route:

```
student/absense
```

But because the `student` routing is before the `student/absense` routing you are never accessing the index route but `student/{student}` because the `{student}` wildcard catches `student/absense` and enters the `StudentController@show` route.

Switching the route definition should fix the problem:

```
Route::resource('student/absense','AbsensesController');
Route::resource('student','StudentsController');
```

Or you could add a hyphen so you never run into a conflict:

```
Route::resource('student','StudentsController');
Route::resource('student-absense','AbsensesController');
```

Comment: Yes you are right its working now because php usual reading from bottom to top. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

With this statement:

```
  return view('student.absense.test');
```

You are trying to load a file inside the absense folder that is named test, but here:

```
Btw **index** is inside absense folder and absense folder is inside student folder.
```

you say that you have a file named index inside that folder and not test. I think that's why you are not getting what you want.

Rename the index file inside absense folder to test or the test file you declared in the index function from test to index.

Comment: that was a mistake. I did not change when i was copying this code here, but im actually using index i just wanted to try with another view so i can figure out why my rout is not working.